# Creating New Matrix which includes consecutive numbers from another array

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I'm trying to create a matrix which is `n x 5`. The matrix would be constructed from another array which includes integer numbers.

All rows would start with the number minus 4 and end with the number from the array. I'm trying to find an efficient method which does not use `for-loop`. 
To illustrate the situation I'm giving an example:

```
b=[6 8 9 11 13 16 17 ];
A=zeros(length(b),5);
```

After using the code I want to obtain:

```
A=[2:6;
   4:8;
   5:9;
   9:13;
   12:16;
   13:17];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with `@plus` or `@minus` as the *operation specifier* on `b` as a column vector and an offset row vector that goes from `-4 to 0` for `@plus` specifier and `4 to 0` for `@minus` specifier as the last argument to it. Thus, the implementations would look like this -

```
bsxfun(@plus,b(:),-4:0)
bsxfun(@minus,b(:),4:-1:0)
```

Sample run -

```
>> b
b =
     6     8     9    11    13    16    17
>> bsxfun(@plus,b(:),-4:0)
ans =
     2     3     4     5     6
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9
     7     8     9    10    11
     9    10    11    12    13
    12    13    14    15    16
    13    14    15    16    17
>> bsxfun(@minus,b(:),4:-1:0)
ans =
     2     3     4     5     6
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9
     7     8     9    10    11
     9    10    11    12    13
    12    13    14    15    16
    13    14    15    16    17
```